# disqus comment to refer to a section of a page

Tags: javascript, disqus

I have a long long HTML page...
separeted in sections (h2)
And I have added disqus at the bottom.

I would like people to write a comment on disqus.

People write a comment and that comment really refers to a certain part of the page.
is there a way to write comments like this:

```
#chapter_14 I think this section should improve

#chapter_3 the first two sentences are wrong...
```

but then to transform #chapter_14 so that it becomes some kind of relative url and moves the main page to the section ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this as you describe with Disqus. Users who know generally take advantage of the fact that we allow `<blockquote>` tags to quote content.

Creating some kind of visual helper might encourage users to do this -- for example a "quote section" button that copies the content to the clipboard with the proper `<blockquote>` tags and then navigates to the `#disqus_thread` anchor with an instruction to paste it.

An interesting extension of this might be to poll our API for comments with your quoted content and display them inline with the content. This would definitely be possible using our posts/list endpoint, which you can find out a little more about here: http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/

Just some ideas, let us know if any stick.